# Selenium PhantomJSDriver - Unable to switch to frame

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

In my Java application I'm trying to switch to Wordpress iframe `content_ifr` with a following java code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("content_ifr");
```

but continuously getting a following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to switch to frame","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"20","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:15910"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\"content_ifr\"}","url":"/frame","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"frame","directory":"/","path":"/frame","relative":"/frame","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/frame","queryKey":{},"chunks":["frame"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d2c0de40-6349-16e5-8bdf-f3a5c98d0edc/frame"}}
```

Driver info:

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false, databaseEnabled=false, version=1.9.8, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.1.0, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

I'm using:

```
selenium 2.47.2
phantomjs-1.9.8-windows
```

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a dirty hack:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
WebElement iframe = null;
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    if("content_ifr".equals(elements.get(i).getAttribute("id"))) {
        iframe = elements.get(i);
        break;
    }
}
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

now it works..

Comment: Why not `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("content_ifr")))`? Also, can you check whether there are two elements on the page with that id? If so, is the iframe the first one or not?

Comment: Still doesn't work correctly.. sometimes content_ifr cannot be found for some reason..

Comment: You probably need an explicit wait to wait for the iframe to be put into the page.

Comment: I placed this logic `driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));` into a loop(with Thread.sleep(5000) between calls) and waiting for `content_ifr` with no success right now..